# Can I compare two files: local and remote on http server without downloading?

Tags: java, android

I want to compare two files (one file is located on local location and second is located on http server). Can I do that without downloading? I want to know that two files is completely the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Hash the files in both sides
2. Get the hash from the server
3. Compare to local file's hash

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what level of comparison you need. I assume you don't want to upload your local copy to the server either.  You could easily take a hash of the file using MD5 or SHA1 and send that hash to the server to compare the files.  If the hashes match they are the same.  If they differ then you could then choose to upload the file for diff type comparison.

Comment: This answer is only partly correct. If the hashes match, they are not necessarily the same (since [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) may occur).

Comment: And how often do hash collisions happen?  The use of the word partly implies this is something that happens enough for concern.  Let's see the probability of a collision with MD5 is 4.3*10-60. So virtually never.  But I guess my answer is 1-4.3*10-60 correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You can create a MD5 or SHA1 checksum und put it next to your file onto the server. Than you'll have to download that file.

You may use http-caching mechanisms (e-tag etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you need this kind of thing ..its not usual condition .

Firstly the file which is locating in your  local server (I guess you can get the size of it )

and the file which is on the http server you need to make web service which can provide you the size of the file ..

so you can easily compare the size of tow file .

Answer (score -1):

I use an app called Beyond Compare to do exactly that. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: I think he wants to check it on the device.

Comment: -1 "Can I do that without downloading?" Beyound compare compares the complete file after downloading it.